# From UI scene to Game. No cameras rendering error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am building a 2D proyect in Unity, when I play the game and try to go from the play button (from MainMenu UI) to the second scene ( 1 on the index value)  y keeps giving me the error of display 1 no cameras rendering. I have experienced this error before and the problem was that the scene was not on the build settings but this is not the case. If anyone could help me I will be really appreciated.

Comment: This question probably does not have anything to do with [tag:unityscript].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have active `GameObject` with `Camera` component on it in the second scene. Use rightclick in the Hierarhy then `Camera`.

You can open `Game` window without starting the game. You can see what this scene will look like in runtime.